How to Solve the problem of Large Size of Docker Image containing ML model with Node APIs?
i have an server for application in which via child Processes in Node.js i am calling python Scripts which are responsible for ML model running.. Server is running good but the issue is of large requirements for ML model running
bidict==0.23.1
mediapipe==0.10.14
numpy==1.26.0
opencv-contrib-python==4.10.0.84
opencv-python==4.10.0.84
pandas==2.2.2
tensorflow==2.17.0

While dockerizing the server. this requirenmets takes upto 3.9GB of size and final image is of approx 5GB large..
this is my dockerFile if any solution can possible
# Use a base image with both Python and Node.js
FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:latest

# Set up the working directory
WORKDIR /home/pn/app

# Switch to root to perform installations
USER root

# Install dependencies required by OpenCV
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
    libglib2.0-0

# Create a virtual environment and install Python dependencies
RUN python -m venv /home/pn/app/venv
ENV PATH="/home/pn/app/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Copy and install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy Node.js app files and install as root
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Switch to the 'pn' user and ensure proper ownership
# RUN chown -R pn:pn /home/pn/app

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Expose the necessary ports
EXPOSE 5000

# Verify Python and Node.js versions
RUN python --version
RUN node --version

# Start the application
CMD ["node", "app.js"]


How large is the base image?  A couple of the Python machine-learning packages are known to be especially large; have you used standard Unix tools like df in an interactive shell, or docker history, to try to figure out where the space might be going?

Why do you think it's a "problem"? This  is known to have huge demands on space
